# Datatable checkbox doesn't work with ajax

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I'm  to use jQuery Datatables for Classic asp and  json https://datatables.net/
Non filter datatable worked checkbox but filter column checkbox does not see other checkbox checked .
Remove filter and check working.

Checkbox value add into textbox

```
var string = $checks.filter(":checked").map(function(i,v){
        return this.value;
        }).get().join(",");
        $('#idler').val(string);
```

[Non filter datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHJMz.png)
[filter datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1AIS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column filter not work jquery

1. $("input:checked").each(function(i)  var string
2. $checks.filter(":checked").map(function(i,v)

I work function javascript

```
var elm = document.getElementById('idler');
var re = new RegExp(text, 'gi');
if (elm.value.match(re)) {
    elm.value = elm.value.replace(re, '');
}
else {
    elm.value += text;
}
```

}